# Wordpress wp_update_post not updating post_name

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a requirement in WordPress, where , if the taxonomy term string is equal to post title, the update the slug (since the permalink rules fail in this case).

**My code is :**

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug', 10,2);
function change_default_slug($post_id, $post) {
  error_log($post_id);
  error_log($post->post_title);
  error_log($post->post_name);

  $taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','names');
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomies,  array("fields" => "names"));
  $terms = array_map('strtolower', $terms);

  error_log('terms :' . json_encode($terms));

  $title = strtolower($post->post_title);
  error_log('title : ' . $title);

  if(in_array($title, $terms)) {

    error_log('yessss');

    $args =  array (
      'ID'        => $post->ID,
      'post_name' => $post->post_name . "-post"
    );
    $result = wp_update_post($update_args);
    error_log('result');
    error_log(json_encode($result));
  } else {
    error_log('noooooooo');

  }
}
```

On required post I am getting logs : Yesss result 0.
The slug is not updating.
Please help on the same. I have tried literally all solutions available for this issue. It has to be done via functions.php

Comment: $result = wp_update_post($update_args); should be $result = wp_update_post(args);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it using : **wp_insert_post()**

```
   $taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','names'); 
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomies,  array("fields" => "all"));

   foreach($terms as $term) {

      if($term->taxonomy == 'category'){
           $categories[] = $term->term_id;
      } else if($term->taxonomy == 'post_tag'){
           $tags[] = $term->term_id;
      }
   }
    .
    .
    .
   //detach the hook to avoid infinite looping of the hook on post insert
   remove_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug', 10,2);

   //insert post
   $result =   wp_insert_post($post, true);

  //attach post tags to the current post (since not by default attached)
  wp_set_post_terms($post_id,$tags,'post_tag');

  //attach post categories to the current post (since not by default attached)
  wp_set_post_terms($post_id,$categories,'category');

  //re-activate the hook
  add_action('save_post', 'change_default_slug', 10,2);
```

Comment: You should provide the parameters in variable `$post` for this to make sense to readers.